# Crispy stroke lines in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I stroke a path, I always get antialiased lines (examples on the left in the image below), but I'd like to have pixel-perfect lines like the one (hand-drawn) on the right. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: Select `Pencil` as the tool in the `Tool:` dropdown.

Comment: If I select the Pencil it exits the "path" section...

Comment: **I mean:** Once you've created a path, with `Pen tool` (or one of the other path tools ) right click the document, select `Stroke path` and in that window choose `Pencil` as the tool. _If you want to adjust the pencil settings, you should do that before right clicking the document by selecting the `Pencil tool` and adjusting the settings, then select the `Pen tool` or what ever.. and continue with the right click._

Comment: I see, thanks. The problem is that Stroke Path is always grayed out, but i can select "Stroke" (or Fill) from the upper menu.

Comment: In that case I would say that what you have is a shape layer. You can't use `Fill path` or `Stroke path` methods if your path is tied to a shape layer.  Before you start drawing with the `Pen tool`, for instance, in the tool options bar at the top left, there is a dropdown that says: `Shape` or `Path` (or if you're using `Ellipse tool` for instance, there's a third option called `Pixel`) select `Path`.  Also make sure that the layer you begin to draw paths in, isn't a Shape layer.

Comment: If however... your path is already tied to a Shape layer and you want to use that path, switching the tool to `path` won't work. You need to convert the Shape into an independent path: **1.** Select the shape layer. **2.** Open `Window > Paths`. **3.** Double click the selected path in that panel and give it a name ( This duplicates it. You could also right click and choose duplicate ). **4.** Once it's duplicated, return back to `Window > Layers`. **5.** Create a new layer. **6.** You can now use `Stroke path` and delete the old Shape layer.

Comment: Turned the comments into an answer. Added something extra at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to disable anti-aliasing for shape layers.

What you can do:

### If you've already drawn a path, but it's on a shape layer:

1. Select the shape layer.
2. Open `Window > Paths`.
3. Double click the selected path in that panel and give it a name ( This duplicates it. You could also right click and choose duplicate ).
4. Once it's duplicated, return back to `Window > Layers`.
5. Create a new layer.
6. With `Pen tool`, right click inside the document and choose: `Stroke Path` and select `Pencil` as the tool.

   - If you want to change the stroke that `Pencil` creates: before right clicking, take `Pencil tool`, edit the tool options, go back to `Pen tool` and continue with the steps above.
7. Delete the old Shape layer ( or hide it.. your call )

### If you are beginning to draw a path:

Take the `Pen tool` and in the tool options ( top left ) there is a dropdown that says: `Shape` or `Path` (or if you're using `Ellipse tool` for instance, there's a third option called `Pixel`) select `Path`.

Also make sure that the layer you're going to be drawing the path on, is not a `Shape layer` because then the new path is just going to be tied to that shape layer and that could be troublesome.

**Once the path is drawn:**  With `Pen tool`, right click inside the document and choose: `Stroke Path` and select `Pencil` as the tool.

If you want to change the stroke that `Pencil` creates: before right clicking, take `Pencil tool`, edit the tool options, go back to `Pen tool` and continue with the steps above.

---

**Alternate methods**

With the "shape tools", such as `Ellipse tool, Rectangle tool, Rounded rectangle tool, etc...` you can select `Pixel` from the dropdown from the tool options ( top left ) and then uncheck "Anti-alias". This is not something you can do with `Pen tool`.

Note that you could draw a shape with `Pen tool` and use `Define custom shape`, select the `Custom shape tool` and use the `Pixel` option to place the shape at any size with aliased edges. Not sure why you'd ever need to do this but I thought I'd mention it anyways.